# Start Windows Service with Java

Tags: java, windows-services

I am trying to start a windows service in java using this

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        String startCom = "net start";
        String startProc = "\"C:/Program Files/Common Files/Apple/Mobile Device Support/bin/AppleMobileDeviceService.exe\"";
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec(startCom + startProc);       
        System.out.println("Starting It");

}
```

It runs with no exceptions but does not start the service. What Am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to use proc.getOutputStream and proc.getErrorStream?

Comment: @skaffman: Does the Java Service Wrapper allow you to start existing Windows services? I can't seem to find that among its list of [features](http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/product-features.html).

Comment: Read http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Comment: If you use that Runtime.exec() method signature, make sure you include a space between "start" and your service name. If you use one of the other method signatures, your executable name will be `net`, and the arguments will be `start` and your service name.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to figure out what the registered service name is, and use that instead of the full executable. For example:

   `net start "Adobe Acrobat Update Service"`

   You can find out the service name by by running `net start` on a command window (which prints a list of all registered services) or by finding the service in the Services control panel by clicking the *Start* button, typing `services.msc`, and pressing *Enter*. If the service name is cryptic, you can right-click the service in the Services control panel and click *Properties* to confirm the executable for that service.
2. You probably need to execute the command with escalated privileges. You can either do this by disabling UAC (not recommended), by launching javaw.exe with elevated privileges when you start your program, or by using a utility like [Elevate.exe](http://jpassing.com/2007/12/08/launch-elevated-processes-from-the-command-line/) to execute any privileged commands.
3. If you're having trouble getting Runtime.exec to do your bidding, try using [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) instead.
4. Lastly, it's a good idea to always read the contents of STDOUT and STDERR (from `Process.getOutputStream()` and `Process.getErrorStream()`). They might contain diagnostic information; but even more importantly, if the buffers fill up while the `Process` is still outputting to them, the `Process` will hang.

Comment: Hello All: Thanks for the help, still not working, I tried net start with just the name from the command line says its invalid name looking for an executable (which does not work either). I guess this leaves me with processbuilder? getErrorStream returns java.io.FileInputStream@21b6d, still trying to look that up...

Comment: Do you get the same error running `net start SERVICENAME` directly on the command line? Regarding the last error you mentioned, you won't be able to use it as a String directly--you'll want to read the contents of the error stream as you would when reading from a FileInputStream or other InputStream: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html

Comment: Hello Rob, Yes its saying Invalid name so I switch back to using this Process proc = rt.exec("net start \"C:/Program Files/Common Files/Apple/Mobile Device Support/bin/AppleMobileDeviceService.exe\"" ); Which produces System error 123 has occurred.
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. This must be something to do with how Im escaping the path to the service, but so far nothing has worked...

Comment: Remember, Windows does not use `/`  for paths, it uses \ (which you'll have to escape in Java String literals). Does `net start "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Apple\Mobile Device Support\bin\AppleMobileDeviceService.exe"` work on the command line? First make sure you can get the command working on the command line, then get Java to execute the same command.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process proc = rt.exec("cmd start /c C:/Program Files/Common Files/Apple/Mobile Device Support/bin/AppleMobileDeviceService.exe");       
    System.out.println("Starting It");
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your main() exits, so your service will die.  In this case, you need to install the service using

```
sc create "servicename" binpath="path",
```

and then start it with

```
sc start "servicename.
```

That is, a service .exe still needs to be installed as a Windows service.